# Copying an entire directory structure and/or skeleton

Tags: filesystems, data

How do we copy an entire directory template/structure or skeleton ?
As nothing in use instruction:

```
Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

  -a, --archive                same as -dR --preserve=all
      --attributes-only        don't copy the file data, just the attributes
      --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file
  -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument
      --copy-contents          copy contents of special files when recursive
  -d                           same as --no-dereference --preserve=links
  -f, --force                  if an existing destination file cannot be
                                 opened, remove it and try again (this option
                                 is ignored when the -n option is also used)
  -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite (overrides a previous -n
                                  option)
  -H                           follow command-line symbolic links in SOURCE
  -l, --link                   hard link files instead of copying
  -L, --dereference            always follow symbolic links in SOURCE
  -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file (overrides
                                 a previous -i option)
  -P, --no-dereference         never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
  -p                           same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
      --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]   preserve the specified attributes (default:
                                 mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible
                                 additional attributes: context, links, xattr,
                                 all
      --no-preserve=ATTR_LIST  don't preserve the specified attributes
      --parents                use full source file name under DIRECTORY
  -R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively
      --reflink[=WHEN]         control clone/CoW copies. See below
      --remove-destination     remove each existing destination file before
                                 attempting to open it (contrast with --force)
      --sparse=WHEN            control creation of sparse files. See below
      --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
                                 argument
  -s, --symbolic-link          make symbolic links instead of copying
  -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
  -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file
  -u, --update                 copy only when the SOURCE file is newer
                                 than the destination file or when the
                                 destination file is missing
  -v, --verbose                explain what is being done
  -x, --one-file-system        stay on this file system
  -Z                           set SELinux security context of destination
                                 file to default type
      --context[=CTX]       like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the SELinux 
                            or SMACK security context to CTX
```

Please give nice guide

Comment: Pleas explain why `-r` does not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: `cp -r`, `rsync`, `tar`, there's a ton of tools that do what you want. What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to copy only the files of type *directory*, recursively and not the other types of files, you can use `pax` (standard but can't deal with arbitrary filenames unless you use non-standard extensions, and I don't know any opensource implementation that are compliant or can deal with arbitrary file names) or `cpio`/`tar` (common but with syntax varying between implementations and not all of them able to deal with arbitrary file names or able to copy all metadata) or `rsync` (only one implementation, but generally not installed by default).

For instance to duplicate the structure (including metadata where possible) found inside the `$src` directory into the `$dst` directory:

With libarchive's `bsdtar`:

```
(
  cd -P -- "$src" &&
    find . -type d -print0 | bsdtar --null -T - -cnf -
) | (cd -P -- "$dst" && bsdtar -xpSf -)
```

With `rsync`:

```
rsync -aAX --include='*/' --exclude='*' -- "$src/" "$dst/"
```

Note that there are some metadata that only `root` can copy (likely ownership and some extended attributes), see also the documentation of `-X` in the `rsync` man page about which extended attributes are preserved.